# How to initialize MySQL database tables for OpenGTS?

Tags: mysql, windows-7

I am trying to install OpenGTS on my system. I have successfully installed all the required software packages as given in the document given [here](http://opengts.sourceforge.net/OpenGTS_Config.pdf). I am stuck at step:
**4) Initialization and Installation Testing** 
I am trying to run the following command as per the document.

> bin\initdb.bat "-rootUser:userName" "-rootPass:userPass"

but I get the following exceptions:

```
[ERROR|DBAdmin.execCommands:873] Exception: DB create error [jdbc:mysql://localh
ost:3306/]
org.opengts.dbtools.DBException: JDBC Error [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.Com
municationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driv
er has not received any packets from the server.]
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBC.. blah blah...
```

Please tell me what is that I am missing in this step-by-step document.

Comment: can we have a tag for OpenGTS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I have to start MySQL demon before I could create tables for GTS. One of my friend helped me with this and I could go through this step.

We need to click on the mysqld.exe in the bin folder of MySql installation.